# better way to avoid call to a member function

Tags: php

I need to know if there is a better way to avoid Call to a member function `xxxx()` on `null`

currently I'm coding as follows but it is cumbersome.

```
if($event->getForm()
                && $event->getForm()->getParent()
                && $event->getForm()->getParent()->getParent()
                && $event->getForm()->getParent()->getParent()->getData()
                && $event->getForm()->getParent()->getParent()->getData()->getComponente()
            ){
                $componente = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getParent()->getData()->getComponente();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $componente, $defaultComponente);
            }
```

Comment: save results in variables, and do it with sequential ifs, that way you call each function only once, and the code gets more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 7 this is actually a catchable Error (if you're using `hhvm` it's a regular Exception):

```
try {
    $componente = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getParent()->getData()->getComponente();
} catch (\Error $e) {
    $componente = null;
}

if ($componente !== null) {
    $formModifier($event->getForm(), $componente, $defaultComponente);
}
```

In PHP 5 there is a workaround using intermediate variables and the `and` keyword instead of `&&`:

```
if (
    $f  = $event->getForm() and
    $p  = $f->getParent()   and
    $p2 = $p->getParent()   and
    $d  = $p2->getData()    and
    $componente = $d->getComponente()
) {
    $formModifier($f, $componente, $defaultComponente);
}
```

If you use `&&` instead of `and` you'll get "undefined variable" notices and this workaround won't work.

Working examples: https://3v4l.org/0S6ps

Comment: This is so nice when you already have a try catch and can just shove `| Error` in the catch (providing the same message can be used etc). Otherwise try catch might be overkill for what would be just an `if`. Nice to know though thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no there is no way, but at least you can do some performance improvement

```
$form = $event->getForm();

if(!$form){
    //do error handling
    return;
}
$parent = $form->getParent();

if(!$parent){
    //do error handling
    return;
}

$p_parent = $parent->getParent();

if(!$p_parent){
    //do error handling
    return;
}

$data = $p_parent->getData();

if(!$data){
    //do error handling
    return;
}

$component = $data->getComponente();
...
```

this way you call each function only once and you can do better error handling

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great example of a bad code. By having a code like this you're breaking several rules and making your life much harder than it should be.
Your code is rigid, fragile, hard to understand and maintain etc.

Simpler is ALWAYS better.

If you can't make your $xx->getComponent() a proper object easily accessible without such ugly nested relationship, you should at least encapsulate the method into something appropriate and use that instead, so if anything changes, you don't have to go full mental and change it all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

This class seems strange in it's creation, but if you are not extracting these methods dynamically using `__call()`, you can use `method_exists()` in a loop inside a function, something similar to:

```
function getMethodChain($class,$arr = ['getForm','getParent','getParent','getData','getComponente'])
{
    # First check the object is set
    if(!is_object($class))
        return false;
    # Loop intended method chain
    foreach($arr as $method) {
        # Check if the method exists in the current class or passed already
        $useClass   =   (!isset($classPass))? $class : $classPass;
        # Check if the method exists in the current class
        if(is_object($useClass) && method_exists($useClass,$method)) {
            # Assign this class/method to use next in the loop
            $classPass  =   $useClass->{$method}();
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    # Just send back
    return (isset($classPass))? $classPass : false;
}
```

The use would be something like:

```
# This will either be the data you expect or false
$componente = getMethodChain($event);
```